# Tap Detection Using Microphone In Browser (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, audio, detection, microphone, tap

**I need a way to detect when people tap their laptop.**
The sound will be captured by the microphone. I want to determine if the tap occurs in the audio stream.
I need to do this in javascript as I want to enable this feature on the webpage.

What way should I go doing this? Do you know any js libraries that can help me?

The only solution that I considered so far is Web Audio API, but I don't like it as it is something recently introduced and is not compatible with many(older versions) of browsers.
https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html

About the solution:

-it shouldn't be flash

-it doesn't need to work on mobile browsers. Just desktop/laptop browsers.

Thank you all in advance.